# Vue: Problem with reload specific page, page with slug

Tags: vue.js

App work fine in developer mode.
When I buil app for production and upload to server I have problem with reloading page.
Error I get i 'The requested URL was not found on this server.'
Reloading in dev mode work fine.
I can't reload page and I can't go direct to some url in app.

Comment: Depending on the deploy server maybe you have some Router errors check this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: Problem is with dynamic routes. Now i need rex expression that allow everything after /shop/products/